# How to allow a non-root user to have only sudo-less capabilities for mkdir

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

My `deploy` user needs to create folders for my deployment method using shipit.js. I cannot find a way to give shipit.js the deploy password. So, I would like to allow `deploy` to make directories without sudo, but not allow all sudo-less activity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: mkdir under a specific location, or mkdir anywhere on the system?

Comment: Is the requirement to be able to make directories without using `sudo`, or to be able to make directories without needing to enter a password? And is it OK if the directories are owned by `deploy`? Is it OK if the directories are owned by `root`?

Comment: @Scott 1. Either 2. Yes 3. Yes

Comment: @grawity Specific location

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of broad options: (1) Modify `/etc/sudoers` to allow `deploy` to run `sudo mkdir` without requiring a password (while leaving all other commands secure), and (2) Make the specified location writable by the `deploy` user (possibly using ACLs).  I suggest that you research these (options like this are discussed widely; you’ll get plenty of results from a search) and come back here if/when you have a more specific question.